# RaspAP connect to WEP WIFI client

Tags: raspbian, wifi

I have a raspberry pi setup with raspAP as a mobile hotspot for when I'm on the go at camping sites. Occasionally I encounter an old WEP network, which I can not connect to. I attempted to install network-config but this can’t be installed in combination with raspAP i think.

Does anyone know how to connect with a WEP WIFI client with raspAP?

Comment: Please add URL to the raspAP you are using.

Comment: WEP is a pain - try converting the password to hex or get them to upgrade their security :-)

Answer (score 1):

WEP has been deprecated for quite awhile but old routers still exist in the wild, as you've found. Not all routers accept hex passwords, but you can try converting an ASCII password using an online tool like [this one](https://www.binaryhexconverter.com/ascii-text-to-hex-converter). A valid WEP key should be 5 or 13 characters *or* a 10- or 26-digit hexadecimal value. Be sure the hex values are unpadded and there are no trailing spaces, e.g., `52617370415069734772656174`.

Paste this value into RaspAP's wifi client passphrase field and try connecting.

Source: developer of RaspAP.

Comment: Thanks for this tip will try that!